# Firebase Storage rules to lookup data on Firestore document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Is it possible to have a Firebase Storage rule that is similar to the get() function of Firestore?

Basically I would like to check the user document in Firestore to allow writes in Storage.

I guess working with claims would be the best solution, but I'm not sure I can use that.

I would like something like this:

```
allow create: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.canDoSomeStuff == true;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's currently not possible for security rules for any Firebase product to reach outside of their own product.  Feel free to [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features) for that.

Comment: I guess it's still the same as of 2020?